# Magento : currency overlaps to price in invoice pdf

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Nigerian currency for as a primary and it displays well in order view, invoice and shipment. But when I am trying to take print the currency overrides the amount.

[image: below is the invoice pdf image in which the currency symbol overlaps the price]

Can anyone tell me how to resolve it.
My Magento version is 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Please use this module - may be it will help you.

**https://marketplace.magento.com/etws-et-currencymanager.html**

also I am finding any better solution for you. If I will get let you know.